# Find initial evidence that a treatment could be not enough to prevent a disease

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, biostatistics, medicine

I have just a basic understanding of statistics so please forgive me for the poor description I'm writing.

I'm trying to design a **small retrospective study** to figure out if I can get some evidence that support the thesis I'm describing below. (I know that this could be weak evidence since it's not a randomized controlled trial but can serve as an input for further studies).

---

Suppose I have a certain disease (pulmunary embolism), for which there is prophilaxis (heparin) which should prevent it most of the time.

The prophilactic dose is fixed for everyone. ***I'd like to demonstrate that the dose should be tailored on the weight of the patient or other risk factors.***

In fact it happens that people on prophilaxis still develop the disease (which is reasonable but maybe could depend on the fixed dose).

How can I find out if that is significant or not?

Given I have access to all the CT scan (which is needed to diagnose the disease), how can I plan a retrospective study to indagate my hypotesis?

Thanks and sorry for the soft question.

---

I'm adding some details.

Prophilaxis with heparin is started on the basis of some criteria (age, previous surgery etc).

When the patient is suspected to have pulmunary embolism (eg doesn't breath normally, other clinical and lab parameters), a pulmunary CT scan is requested.

Having access to CT scans I can subdivide the population in 4:

A) people who did prophilaxis who develop pulmunary embolism.

B) people who did prophilaxis who did not develop pulmunary embolism.

C) people who did not prophilaxis who develop pulmunary embolism.

D) people who did not prophilaxis who did not develop pulmunary embolism.

I still miss all the people who did prophilaxis that never developed symptoms of pulmunary embolism and never did a CT scan.

Ideally I would want to demonstrate that people that are heavier and did the prophilaxis with fixed dose develop more frequently pulmunary embolism than those who are lighter.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know how to predict which patients the prophylaxis fails for? Do you want to know if different doses of heparin would give different outcomes? Or something else?

Comment: I'd like to determine to what extent that dose is sufficient to prevent pulmonary embolism and if patient treated with that dose have less extensive embolism that those that are not treated. Note that the dose is fixed and I can study it retrospectively. I imagine that the dose works better for lighter people...

Comment: To be able to tell if that does is sufficient you need an untreated control group, or at least one with a different dose. In your question you do not specify whether you have that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do have many CT pulmunary scan, some of them show pulmunary embolism, some not. A CT scan is done when there is suspicious of embolism, eg they don't breath normally. The population that undergoes this CT scan is heterogeneous, some of them have done that prophilaxis some others haven't (based on some criteria).

Comment: It's quite possible that no dose will guarantee 100% prevention (and there will be good reasons to avoid very high doses). Rather than seeking 100% prevention it may be better to think about at what point the diminishing expected returns of additional heparin is not worth the additional problems caused by increasingly large doses of it. At some point you're costing yourself more than its worth (from a pure help/harm point of view), and since heparin also costs money, you'd want to avoid increasing heparin dosage before that point. Maybe aim for nearly all instead, and track the complications.

Comment: @glen_b right! But for that a randomized controlled trial would be needed I suppose. Given the resource I have I can only start a retrospective study... What can I achieve with that in this scenario?

Comment: I was mainly seeking a slight edit of the title and first few paragraphs to more clearly express an achievable goal.

Comment: @Glen_b I further edited the question including your suggestions. Could you please have a look at it? I'd be grateful for any hint.

Comment: @mdewey I edited the question to add the details you requested. What do you think?